# Removing colon search operator in shopify searchbar

Tags: javascript, search, shopify

I'm currently trying to remove the : as a search operator in Shopify search, I've added an * to the end of the search string using javascript but finding a colon in a string and removing everything before it then adding an * to the end seems like a very complicated way to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Currently products named 444:55 are not returning results because the search is searching for products 55 in 444, ideally I'd like to be able to disable the search in properties of a : in my search bar.

Just searching for 444* when a user searches 444:55 would work too. I'm already adding the * to perform a wildcard search.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, all that you need to do is replace `:` with `\:`. You can achieve it with javascript like that:

```
var q = //it is your query string
q.replace(":","\:")
```